# dYdX event log signature hash

Tags: events

dYdX has an event called LogDeposit(address indexed accountOwner, uint256 accountNumber, uint256 market, BalanceUpdate update, address from) within their [SoloMargin](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e0447b19bb6ecfdae1e4ae1694b0c3659614e4e#code) contract. I am trying to get the signature hash for this using the following code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import keccak
keccak_hash = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
keccak_hash.update(b'LogDeposit(address,uint256,uint256,BalanceUpdate,address)')
print(keccak_hash.hexdigest())
```

This produces the following signature hash: ad66b490ac5d24d41e7e33a2a9ac6645bf66b577553f31d1e2917df2f83f15a6. However, I do not think it is right. When I search for this topic in etherscan nothing is returned.

I am wondering if it has to do with the BalanceUpdate parameter. I am used to searching for the other types such as address and uint256, but this one I haven't seen and do not know if I am doing this right.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what `BalanceUpdate` is composed of? dYdX contains many contracts, I'm not easily able to find it.

Comment: I updated the original question. It is within their [Solo Margin](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e0447b19bb6ecfdae1e4ae1694b0c3659614e4e#code) contract. The Balance update is a struct that contains the following:

`
    struct BalanceUpdate {
        Types.Wei deltaWei;
        Types.Par;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calculating the signature of an event that uses structs, **each struct is represented as a tuple of the types of the variables it contains**. To create the tuple for your question, we need to look at the source of `SoloMargin`.

Based on the source published to [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e0447b19bb6ecfdae1e4ae1694b0c3659614e4e#code), I extracted the code needed to create the event:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.7;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract SoloMiningLogEvent {

    struct Wei {
        bool sign;
        uint256 value;
    }

    struct Par {
        bool sign;
        uint128 value;
    }

    struct BalanceUpdate {
        Wei deltaWei;
        Par newPar;
    }

    event LogDeposit(
        address indexed accountOwner,
        uint256 accountNumber,
        uint256 market,
        BalanceUpdate update,
        address from
    );

}
```

We can see that `BalanceUpdate` is composed of two structs:

- `Wei`, a tuple of `(bool,uint256)`
- `Par`, a tuple of `(bool,uint128)`

So our tuple representation for `BalanceUpdate` is:

```
((bool,uint256),(bool,uint128))
```

Thus the entire signature to generate the hash is written as:

```
LogDeposit(address,uint256,uint256,((bool,uint256),(bool,uint128)),address)
```

which results in a hash of:

```
0x2bad8bc95088af2c247b30fa2b2e6a0886f88625e0945cd3051008e0e270198f
```

Answer (score 3):

This event's signature is:

```
0x2bad8bc95088af2c247b30fa2b2e6a0886f88625e0945cd3051008e0e270198f
```

This is keccak256 hash of the following string:

```
LogDeposit(address,uint256,uint256,((bool,uint256),(bool,uint128)),address)
```